# Forward subdomain1.example.com to subomain2.example2.com using .htaccess

Tags: domain, forwarding, htaccess, subdomain, url-rewriting

### My Goal

My main website is being hosted by a 3rd party server (Netfirms to be precise). I want most of my content hosted there.  However, I am running an employee portal on a local server. The portal relies on Python scripts which are not supported on Netfirms. The local server is reachable using a DDNS URL (`localserver.dyndns.com`, for example). I have setup a subdomain with my webserver host (`portal.example.com`, for example).

When employees browse to `portal.example.com`, I want the content served from `localserver.dyndns.com`. While Netfirms allowed me to create the redirect, their system simply generates an `index.hml` with the target url (`localserver.dyndns.com`) in a frameset. This, of course, destroys the responsiveness of the site.

### What I've Tried

The easiest not frame-reliant solution was to create a `.htaccess` file containing the following:

```
Redirect /index.html http://localserver.dyndns.com
```

While that does redirect traffic to `localserver.dyndns.com`, the URL changes, so employees see that they are not at `portal.example.com` anymore. I have tried a few different rewrite condtions/rules to no success.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localserver.dyndns.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^portal.example.com$ http://localserver.dydns.com/$1
```

I've even tried with(out) quotes and/or leading `\` for "special" characters (`\:`, `\/`,`\.`, for example), in seemingly endless variations.  I either get `500 - Internal Server Error`, `Access Restricted`, `401 - Not Found`

Nothing seems to work.  What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to redirect, if you only serve content from `localserver.dyndns.com` under `portal.example.com`, and want to use `portal.example.com` as URL.

Create a DNS record for portal.example.com, as CNAME with value `localserver.dyndns.com`.

It will point `portal.domain.com` to whatever is the current IP of `localserver.dyndns.com`, and will not rewrite URL.

Comment: When I do this, I get a `Server Not Found` error.  I verified that I can access `localserver.dyndns.com` directly, just fine.  When I try from `portal.example.com`, I get the error saying, `Server Not Found - Firefox cannot find the server at portal.example.com`

Comment: did you add portal.example.com CNAME record properly, you might be caching DNS on your side also? Visit http://www.mxtoolbox.com/CNAMELookup.aspx and check portal.example.com, and see what t returns.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I checked and confirmed the TTL is another 60 minutes yet, so patients is required, then we shall see.